# v-if and v-else shows while page is loading?

Tags: vue.js

Problem is that both divs shows on load. I tried to use `v-cloak` only on one but its not working. If i put on parent div then its not look good while is hidden. Any suggestion how can i display only one div while page is loading, but without v-cloak?

```
<div class="center_image" v-if="avatarImageSet">
    <div class="checked">
        <div class="seller_image {{ in_role('BusinessUsers') ? 'agency' : '' }}">
            <img src="{{ home_asset('img/very_big_user_icon.png') }}" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="check_profile business">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="center_image" v-else>
    <div class="checked">
        <div class="seller_image">
            <img v-bind:src="user_credentials.avatar" alt="Avatar"/>
        </div>
        <div class="check_profile business">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible to create a fiddle reproducing it?

Comment: only adding v-cloak won't help. You will also need to add the corresponding css. A good approach can also be adding v-cloak the "root" component of your app and adding [v-cloak] { display: none; } to your css. Then nothing will show until vue loaded

Comment: i added v-clock in css..

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because of other errors in your code, like:

1. `<img src="{{ home_asset('img/very_big_user_icon.png') }}" alt="" />`, you should use v-bind with src
2. `class="seller_image {{ in_role('BusinessUsers') ? 'agency' : '' }}"` You should be using dynamic class binding here.

See modified code:

```
<div class="center_image" v-if="avatarImageSet">
    <div class="checked">
        <div class="seller_image" :class="{`yourclass`: in_role('BusinessUsers') === 'agency'}">
            <img :src="home_asset('img/very_big_user_icon.png')" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="check_profile business">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="center_image" v-else>
    <div class="checked">
        <div class="seller_image">
            <img v-bind:src="user_credentials.avatar" alt="Avatar"/>
        </div>
        <div class="check_profile business">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this might be in a laravel context so the stuff might be correct